# Read/write errors on shared NTFS

Tags: 11.10, windows, ntfs

Well, i suppose 'errors' is not the best way of putting it, but anyway.

Due to the usage of my computer, i have set it up to dual-boot Windows 7 and ubuntu 11.10. Windows is in it's own partition, ubuntu and it's swap partition are sharing a logical partition, and i have 3rd partition formatted to NTFS which is shared between the two operating systems.

However, this seems to introduce a fair few strange occurrences. The issue of Nautilus being unable to send files to the rubbish bin (which i am yet to find a definitive answer t) is one, as well as having gigabytes of data disappearing from the drive as if it never existed

In the case of the latter, i transferred ~20GB of files onto the partition from an external drive. Several hours later i needed to briefly boot windows (which had been hibernating). while in windows i went to move a few more files across, to find the original files had completely disappeared. This was still the case when i returned to ubuntu

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i gues is the same thing with me, but in my case everything is ok when i use Ubuntu, but when i change to Xubuntu,the same happens to me.
About 100gb is kind "lost", but, in my case i solved, by remove ntfs config tool, weh i do this, i can get my data back, i can see the amount off 100gb, and acess them.
Then i try to change some off the date and i cant', then i reboot, and after this  i installing MountManager. remenber to keep with ntfs-3g( look in the Synaptic)

After this i mount with this program and all my data is visible and i can do what i whant, rename, delete, edit.

I hope i help you.

Comment: Having a bit of difficulty understanding your answer, but if you are suggesting i use NTFS-3G, i already do (It comes shipped with Ubuntu). MountManager looks interesting, i'll check it out next time i get the chance.